# Find users who bookmarked a question?

Tags: support, data-explorer, bookmarks

Is there any data explorer query that allows to find the users who bookmarked a specific question?

**EDIT**:

I tried searching for a direct hit on [data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer) but didn't find any post having a descriptive title for this functionality.

As linked in the comments, two versions of the query can be found here [who-favourited-this-question](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/954306/who-favourited-this-question), and here [Users who bookmarked a certain question](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1309027/users-who-bookmarked-a-certain-question).

Additional information on SEDE is available in the linked duplicate targets.

Comment: Yes, query for 'favorite' votes, see the duplicate for why it's called that. Users that bookmarked a specific post will have voted with that type of vote on the post.

Comment: This is also covered in the SEDE schema documentation (second duplicate link).

Comment: Finally, this query takes a post id, and lists who has bookmarked it: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/954306/who-favourited-this-question, e.g. [all users that bookmarked the SEDE schema post](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/954306/who-favourited-this-question?QuestionID=2677).

Comment: [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1309027/users-who-bookmarked-a-certain-question?PostId=11227809) is a list of (almost all) users who bookmarked [Why is processing a sorted array faster than processing an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/4751173) (SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning.)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I would argue that although the query linked by @Glorfindel turns out to be simple, the posts linked as duplicate make the info hard to find (by title) and don't contain a ready-to-use query. I searched the `data-explorer` tag and there wasn't any obvious *"hit"*. Most folks interested in a given functionality don't know SQL, and just want to directly find a query by title.

Comment: @bad_coder: that was not clear from your question, however. We went out of our way to get you all the information for possible different interpretations of your question. Do always share your research when asking a question!

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you for the help and guidance. Perhaps this post should be kept as a sign post for people searching the tag for a direct hit by title??